# Powershell query AD group

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script to query AD groups to pull back the users part of that group. I can currently do it if i hard code the group into the script but i am looking to make it user interactive by allowing the user to enter the AD group the are looking for.

I have tried using Read-Host to enter the variable to pull back but it doesn't pull back no results but if i hard code it it does.

```
$group = Read-Host 'Please enter a AD Group!'
Get-ADGroupMember -identity '$group' -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Property DisplayName | Select SamAccountName,Name,ObjectClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change you quotes from single quotes to double quotes ([about_quoting_rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6)).

```
$group = Read-Host 'Please enter a AD Group!'
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "$group" -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Property DisplayName | Select SamAccountName,Name,ObjectClass
```

The double quotes allow the Variable to be substituted. Also in this case, when passing the variable into the `Get-ADGroupMember` cmdlet, quotes around the variable are not needed.